# ExecuteXmlReaderAsync doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.5, async-await

I'm trying to implement XML reading from MSSQL using new async methods in .NET 4.5.

I have the following code

```
var xmlReader = await sqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReaderAsync();

while (await xmlReader.ReadAsync())
{
    var doc = (MyDocument)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    await Process(doc);
}
```

and it fails with **Set XmlReaderSettings.Async to true if you want to use Async Methods.**.

I have checked decompiled sources of ExecuteXmlReaderAsync and I can see that it uses one of this settings:

```
private static readonly XmlReaderSettings DefaultXmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings()
{
  ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
};
private static readonly XmlReaderSettings DefaultXmlReaderSettingsCloseInput = new       XmlReaderSettings()
{
  ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment,
  CloseInput = true
};
```

so it looks like ExecuteXmlReaderAsync is not implemented well.

Please advice if you have any experience to use this method successfully.

UPD: xmlReader.Settings.Async is readonly so it should be set when the object is created

Comment: are opening the connection using async methods? await conn.OpenAsync();

Comment: yes, smth like await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();

Answer (score 2):

I think you're exactly right about the source of this problem. If I use reflection to change the settings in the private field you mentioned, it seems to work.

```
var settingsField = typeof(SqlXml)
    .GetField("DefaultXmlReaderSettingsCloseInput",
              BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var settings = (XmlReaderSettings)settingsField.GetValue(null);
settings.Async = true;
```

Note that this is a dirty hack, which may stop working at any moment. And I don't really know what I'm doing, so this may not actually work properly, or it might have some unintended consequences. Because of that, I would be very careful when using this.

Also, I think you should [report this as a bug to Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/).

Comment: thank you for your advice. I've reported the bug to MSFT. You can vote for it here https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/777166/executexmlreaderasync-doesnt-work-as-expected

Comment: Well, it's 2018 and this bug is still occurring.

Comment: @ScubaSteve Looking at the source code, it seems this has been fixed in .Net Core, but not in .Net Framework. Since the old bug report is no longer accessible, I'm not sure what happened to it. You might want to report it again to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=61).

Comment: There's a constuctor in XmlReader that will take an XmlReader and an XmlReaderSettings. However, if you initialize this way, it will override SOME settings. 

Seems like a bad interface to me, but that's how they did it. I wound up using a different constructor for my purpose, and it worked fine.

So, not a bug actually.

Comment: I could not find this report on the 'new' UserVoice forum, so I created one. Feel free to upvote.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/926539/sqlcommandexecutexmlreaderasync-returns-an-xmlread.html